# Recursively count occurrences of a word in identically named files in different directories

Tags: bash, shell, grep, wc

I've got several different directories that contain different versions of some files. I want to count a symbol in all versions of the same file. Here is an example of the hierarchy.

```
directory
    version1
        1_file.txt
        2_file.txt
        ...
    version2
        1_file.txt
        2_file.txt 
        ... 
    ...
```

I've tried the following:

```
symbol=\>

for i in 1 2 3; do
    grep -roh $symbol $i\_file.txt | wc -w;
done
```

Comment: add a */ before the $i in the grep and you are done (if your cwd is directory) and you don't need the -r flag.

Comment: You don't need loop at all: `grep -oh "$symbol" */{1..3}_file.txt | wc -w`. Also `-r` switch is redundant, perhaps just `grep -roh "$symbol" . | wc -w` is sufficient for you.

Comment: You also have an extra backslash before file.txt on the `grep` line

Comment: I believe there's a POSIX  "-c" option to grep to print a count of matching lines for each input file.  surely that must ..count for something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name \[123]_file.txt -exec cat {} + | tr -sc \> \\n | wc -l
```

...will work for sequences of your single character example. But if the string is more complex, then is probably a good idea to go with the `-o`nly GNU switch to `grep`. Like:

```
find . -name \[123]_file.txt -exec grep -o \> {} + | wc -l
```